# Does Palantir foundry provides a feature of sending email on successful completion of job?

Tags: email, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

We have written a pyspark code to create a report which we needed in a specific format. The requirement is to send email once the job gets executed successfully with the link of report. I understand how to send a notification on failures, but is it possible to send email on success. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Palak, would yourstack.example.com/workspace/documentation/product/actions/notifications work for you?

Comment: updating docs link: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/notifications/

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72285748/palantir-foundry-informing-users-by-e-mail-about-successful-build/72286337#72286337

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Palantir Foundry informing users by e-mail about successful build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72285748/palantir-foundry-informing-users-by-e-mail-about-successful-build)