# Palantir Foundry informing users by e-mail about successful build

Tags: palantir-foundry

I would like to send several users an automatic e-mail informing about a successful dataset update (running a transformation) in Palantir. Is there any option except Ontology notification actions?

Comment: Similar question to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71107882/does-palantir-foundry-provides-a-feature-of-sending-email-on-successful-completi

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe your users to the data health "build completion" and they will get a foundry notification, which they can configure to land on their email.

If the goal is to send a custom email, then it's not possible.

You can hack around it by using maggrite with an export rest task, to send an http request to an external service that knows how to send your custom emails.